# Mysql add duplicated data although the controls

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I've a problem to adding datas in a mysql table. I've create a simple newsletter system. System added sent email address to tasks table and its checking before sent if its already sent. But everytime added duplicated records for example; my email list contain 3000 record but table shows 6000 record.

Here is my table structure and queries;

**Subscriber table**

```
ID   subscriber_mail
--------------------
1    mail1@gmail.com
2    mail2@gmail.com
3    mail3@gmail.com
4    mail4@gmail.com
```

**Task Table**

```
ID   subscriber_mail  CID
---------------------------
1    mail1@gmail.com    1
2    mail2@gmail.com    1
3    mail3@gmail.com    1
4    mail4@gmail.com    1
```

**Subscriber Fetching and Recording**

```
 $query = "
    SELECT 
            S.* 
    FROM 
            subscribers AS S
            LEFT JOIN tasks AS T ON (T.CID=". CAMPAIGN_ID ." AND S.subscriber_mail=T.subscriber_mail)
            LEFT JOIN unsubscribes AS U ON (U.CID=". CAMPAIGN_ID ." AND S.subscriber_mail=U.subscriber_mail)
    WHERE
                (T.subscriber_mail IS NULL) 
            AND (U.subscriber_mail IS NULL) 

    ";


$opSubs = $myconn->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($myconn));
while($opSubsRs = $opSubs->fetch_assoc()){
     -- SMTP connection --
     if($mail->Send()){
         $myconn->query("INSERT INTO tasks SET
                CID=1,
                subscriber_mail='". $opSubsRs['subscriber_mail'] ."'
        ");
     }

}
```

So, this system works fine for my localhost and Namecheap, Godaddy without duplicated records, but some hosting services adding same records in task table. It could be `sql_mode` or `NULL`, `BINARY` issue? DB engine using MyISAM.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting into the table you should check if the email already exists.

Example

```
$query = "SELECT email from subscribers";
```

Fetch that query, then check if email exists after

```
if($query->fetch->rowcount < 1){
$query = "Insert into subscribers(email) values (email)"

}
```

You also shouldn’t insert the id manually just turn on auto increment.

Comment: yes, but subscriber fetch query select only unsent mails with JOIN as (T.subscriber_mail IS NULL)  if I check task list in this loop it could be decrease system performance? If I try to check task table with 1m record in each loop?

Comment: @GökhanAYVAZ Can you maybe save the one you send into a file then load it from it. This way the performance is not a problem and also depending on the email size performance shouldn't be a problem.